Typo3 ajax call very slow on windows xampp
It starts already during logon to backend:
http://localhost/typo3_13_4_0ip/typo3/ajax/login/preflight with this response: {"capabilities":{"cookie":true,"referrer":true}}   takes 8 seconds
getting cache tokens like:  http://localhost/typo3_13_4_0ip/typo3/ajax/icons/cache?token=b2599c41e43cf522fb05a3a3b51307333ab6d32a  with minimal response takes 9 Seconds.
Getting layout token to open in introduction package a sample page
http://localhost/typo3_13_4_0ip/typo3/module/web/layout?token=546ef8722d70c7dc3e3a48b11c66a3d2b66a06df&id=79
takes 12 seconds
cpu and memory is low round about 10%  , machine is a p1 with enough resources. All cache settings like suggestions:
php settings
memory_limit = 2048M
post_max_size = 40M
upload_max_filesize = 40M

Optimize MySQL settings:
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 512M
innodb_log_file_size = 128M
max_allowed_packet = 128M

changing from localhost to 127.0.0.1 does not make a difference.
Is there any possibilty to spped this up. XDebug is even off.

is it also so slow if you set memory_limit to 256M or 512M only?

actually it does not make any difference. It is not faster with less memory limit
